# Why can't I rewrite my SD card?

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-jessie, raspbian-stretch

I have SD Card with Raspbian Jessie. I want to have there completely new Raspbian Stretch. I booted LiveCD and did

```
dd bs=4M if=2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/sdc conv=fsync
```

However, after I launched my Raspberry Pi with the rewritten SD card, there's still Jessie with all my files in /home/pi directory.

What happened, why didn't it work?

EDIT: I tried again with suggestions from the 2 answers:

```
root@kali:/tmp# ls -l /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 Feb  8 18:05 /dev/sdc
root@kali:/tmp# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 29.6 GiB, 31724666880 bytes, 61962240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xea0e7380

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         8192   131071   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2       131072 61962239 61831168 29.5G 83 Linux
root@kali:/tmp# dd bs=4M if=2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch-lite.img of=/dev/sdc conv=fsync
443+0 records in
443+0 records out
1858076672 bytes (1.9 GB, 1.7 GiB) copied, 1017.9 s, 1.8 MB/s
root@kali:/tmp# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 29.6 GiB, 31724666880 bytes, 61962240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xea0e7380

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         8192   131071   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2       131072 61962239 61831168 29.5G 83 Linux
root@kali:/tmp# mount /dev/sdc2 /foo
root@kali:/tmp# cat /foo/etc/debian_version
8.0
root@kali:/tmp# touch /foo/home/pi/bar
root@kali:/tmp# ls -l /foo/home/pi/bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb  8 18:39 /foo/home/pi/bar
```

Comment: Try write it with `/dev/zero`, then write the image again.

Comment: Didn't help :). I also tried with Etcher run on Linux, but it also didn't help even tough it said that flashing had been successful. I guess the card is broken in a weird way.

Comment: My next guess is a defective SD card or SD card controller. Did you try using another card reader?

Comment: Yes, I changed the reader.

Answer (score 1):

My **guess** is, when you first issued this command, there was no device node /dev/sdc, so dd just copied the image file within your filesystem.

`# ls -l /dev/sdc
-rw------- 1 pi users 1050542343  6. Feb 09:27 /dev/sdc`

That's a copy of your image. It must read

`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32  6. Feb 09:27 /dev/sdc`

instead. That's a block special —a type of device node—, you can see it from the `b` in the first column.

UDEV won't create a block special at that place as long a regular file sits there. You have to remove the regular file by hand, if there was one.

Comment: It's not the case here, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you accidently switched your SD card to lock mode.  Unlock it.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could have locked it. It's a MicroSD card put directly into the reader. Please also see my updated question - I was able to touch a file after I mounted / partition, and then the file was shown by ls.